# How to serialize and deserialize DateTime with Windows.Data.Json

Tags: c#, json, datetime, windows-8

I can serialise and deserialize my `Json` (kinda hard because I can't cast `JsonObject` to my class) and there is only `GetString()`, `GetNumber()` and `GetObject()` methods. How can I serialize my `DateTime`?

Comment: Use generic method  `Newton.Json.JsonConvert.DeserilizeObject<YourClass>(yourJsonString);`

Comment: Sorry, but isn't it .net framework library? Library should target 'netCore',

Comment: @TalhaTalipAçıkgöz are you using .NET Core?

Comment: I think Windows 8 uses netCore, because I tried to use Newtonsoft but it gave an error like it should target netCore instead of netFramework.

Comment: There is supprt for .NET Core I think: [https://www.nuget.org/packages/CoreCompat.Newtonsoft.Json/](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CoreCompat.Newtonsoft.Json/)

Comment: JSON does not support dates. You will have encode it into a form that JSON supports.

Comment: @Fabio Looks like that's it, I will try it as soon as I can

Comment: @Raymond Chen I know that Json doesn't support dates. My question is how to serialize it

Comment: DateTime has a format string that is well-suited to serialization.